# How we can perform sorting based on (score(solr attribute) + color(variant) + sequence(variant)) for SOLR?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

In SAP Hybris, I have a requirement like SOLR like sorting should be done with combination of following attributes:

1. score: desc
2. color: alphabetical
3. sequenceNumber: asc

E.g., [image]

Here, product with score 3 should be display at 1st in SOLR result.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: are you applying the sorting sort=field1 asc, field2 desc etc....In your case it would be like sort=score desc,colour asc,sequenceNumber asc...but if field1 is "score", the second sort is not considered if "score" is not same on two documents...very rare case

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with **SolrSort** that can be defined for **SolrIndexedType** and you can use the defined sort by *code* afterward